# How to use aggregate functions in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have 2 tables

1. students
2. payments

In students table I have fields like

```
student_id(Primary key),
student_name, 
student_university, 
student_counselor
```

In payments table I have fields like

```
payment_id(Primary key),
student_id(Foreign key reference to students table), 
payable,
paid, 
balance
```

[image]

I am trying to achive:

- Display the result in the form below i.e each counselor has their students in different university.
- The total number of students belongs to particular university from particular counselor and how much amount is payable, paid and balance as shown in the table above.

Any insight?

Comment: for this output you have to use join query with group by

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Create statement for student table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `university` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `counselor` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Create statement  payment table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `payment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payable` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `paid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `balance` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK payment student_id student id_idx` (`student_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK payment student_id student id` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Students and payments data insertion**

```
INSERT INTO `student` (`name`, `university`, `counselor`) VALUES ('student 1', 'u 1', 'c 1');
INSERT INTO `student` (`name`, `university`, `counselor`) VALUES ('student 2', 'u 1', 'c 1');
INSERT INTO `student` (`name`, `university`, `counselor`) VALUES ('student 3', 'u 1', 'c 2');
INSERT INTO `student` (`name`, `university`, `counselor`) VALUES ('student 4', 'u 1', 'c 2');
INSERT INTO `student` (`name`, `university`, `counselor`) VALUES ('student 5', 'u 2', 'c 3');
INSERT INTO `student` (`name`, `university`, `counselor`) VALUES ('student 6', 'u 2', 'c 3');
INSERT INTO `student` (`name`, `university`, `counselor`) VALUES ('student 7', 'u 2', 'c 4');
INSERT INTO `student` (`name`, `university`, `counselor`) VALUES ('student 8', 'u 2', 'c 4');
INSERT INTO `payment` (`student_id`, `payable`, `paid`, `balance`) VALUES ('1', 500, 300, 200);
INSERT INTO `payment` (`student_id`, `payable`, `paid`, `balance`) VALUES ('2', 500, 300, 200);
INSERT INTO `payment` (`student_id`, `payable`, `paid`, `balance`) VALUES ('3', 400, 400, 400);
INSERT INTO `payment` (`student_id`, `payable`, `paid`, `balance`) VALUES ('4', 400, 400, 400);
INSERT INTO `payment` (`student_id`, `payable`, `paid`, `balance`) VALUES ('5', 100, 200, 300);
INSERT INTO `payment` (`student_id`, `payable`, `paid`, `balance`) VALUES ('6', 51, 52, 53);
```

And here what we have:

```
mysql> select * from student;
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
| id | name      | university | counselor |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | student 1 | u 1        | c 1       |
|  2 | student 2 | u 1        | c 1       |
|  3 | student 3 | u 1        | c 2       |
|  4 | student 4 | u 1        | c 2       |
|  5 | student 5 | u 2        | c 3       |
|  6 | student 6 | u 2        | c 3       |
|  7 | student 7 | u 2        | c 4       |
|  8 | student 8 | u 2        | c 4       |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)


mysql> select * from payment;
+----+------------+---------+------+---------+
| id | student_id | payable | paid | balance |
+----+------------+---------+------+---------+
|  1 |          1 |     500 |  300 |     200 |
|  2 |          2 |     500 |  300 |     200 |
|  3 |          3 |     400 |  400 |     400 |
|  4 |          4 |     400 |  400 |     400 |
|  5 |          5 |     100 |  200 |     300 |
|  6 |          6 |      51 |   52 |      53 |
+----+------------+---------+------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**query itself to select all counselor:**

```
SELECT 
    counselor,
    university,
    COUNT(name) AS 'no of students',
    SUM(payment.payable) AS payable,
    SUM(payment.paid) AS paid,
    SUM(payment.balance) AS balance
FROM
    student
        LEFT JOIN
    payment ON payment.student_id = student.id
GROUP BY counselor;
```

**result:**

```
mysql>     SELECT
    ->         counselor,
    ->         university,
    ->         COUNT(name) AS 'no of students',
    ->         SUM(payment.payable) AS payable,
    ->         SUM(payment.paid) AS paid,
    ->         SUM(payment.balance) AS balance
    ->     FROM
    ->         student
    ->             LEFT JOIN
    ->         payment ON payment.student_id = student.id
    ->     GROUP BY counselor;
+-----------+------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+
| counselor | university | no of students | payable | paid | balance |
+-----------+------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+
| c 1       | u 1        |              2 |    1000 |  600 |     400 |
| c 2       | u 1        |              2 |     800 |  800 |     800 |
| c 3       | u 2        |              2 |     151 |  252 |     353 |
| c 4       | u 2        |              2 |    NULL | NULL |    NULL |
+-----------+------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+
```

*Also you don't have to use `student` prefix on all fields in `student` table. It's obvious that `name` in `student` table means student name and so on.*

**And here is simply php code to print table.**

This is db connect class so you can skip it:

```
define('DB_MAIN', 'localhost|someroot|some|db');

class my_db{

    private static $databases;
    private $connection;

    public function __construct($connDetails){
        if(!is_object(self::$databases[$connDetails])){
            list($host, $user, $pass, $dbname) = explode('|', $connDetails);
            $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
            self::$databases[$connDetails] = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        }
        $this->connection = self::$databases[$connDetails];
    }

    public function fetchAll($sql){
        $args = func_get_args();
        array_shift($args);
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($args);
         return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}


$db = new my_db(DB_MAIN);
```

**main php code itself:**

```
$universities = $db->fetchAll('SELECT distinct university FROM student');
$counselors = $db->fetchAll('SELECT distinct counselor FROM student');
$payments_ = $db->fetchAll(' SELECT
    counselor,
    university,
    COUNT(name) AS \'no of students\',
    SUM(payment.payable) AS payable,
    SUM(payment.paid) AS paid,
    SUM(payment.balance) AS balance
FROM
    student
        LEFT JOIN
    payment ON payment.student_id = student.id
GROUP BY counselor;');

$payments = [];

foreach ($payments_ as $payment)
    $payments[$payment->counselor][$payment->university] = $payment;
?>



<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" >counselor</td>
<?php
    foreach ( $universities as $key => $university){ ?>

        <td colspan="4" ><?=$university->university ?> </td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ( $universities as $university){?>
        <td>no of students</td>
        <td>payable</td>
        <td>paid</td>
        <td>balance</td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ( $counselors as $counselor){?>
    <?php foreach ( $universities as $key => $university){
        $payment = $payments[$counselor->counselor][$university->university];
    ?>
        <?php if(!$key){?>
        <td><?=$counselor->counselor?></td>
        <?php } ?>
        <td><?=(int)$payment->{'no of students'}?></td>
        <td><?=number_format($payment->payable,0,',','')?></td>
        <td><?=number_format($payment->paid,0,',','')?></td>
        <td><?=number_format($payment->balance,0,',','')?></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

**html result**

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">counselor</td>

    <td colspan="4">u 1 </td>

    <td colspan="4">u 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>no of students</td>
    <td>payable</td>
    <td>paid</td>
    <td>balance</td>
    <td>no of students</td>
    <td>payable</td>
    <td>paid</td>
    <td>balance</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c 1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c 2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>800</td>
    <td>800</td>
    <td>800</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c 3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>151</td>
    <td>252</td>
    <td>353</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c 4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Magnificent job. +50 is too small for such an answer.

Comment: +1 for so much effort! Cool... but you don't have to provide all those things for the OP. Btw, he's just asking for "any insight" :D

Comment: @rhavendc remember that Stack Overflow's primary goal is to provide *all* developers with knowledge, not only one who asked. You have to always keep this in mind when answering.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes I know that but it's not what I meant (sorry, I picked the wrong words). His answer is good but (in my point of view) it makes... ... ...anyway, I'll stop explaining for it may result only to nothing. You'll not going to accept it anyway, I guess.

Comment: @rhavendc Not sure I understand what are you talking about. I am not the OP, so I have no means to accept nor award here.

Comment: @Sha its not excellent, its just  basic example to get you an idea

Comment: Nice answer indeed. Let's make it perfect: 1. numeric values (`payable`, `paid`, `balance`) should be stored with a numeric type (`INT` or `DECIMAL`). 2. one of those  three columns duplicates information (can be calculated from the other two columns). Depending on what information is required most frequently, one of them should go.

Comment: The result data is a lil bit wrong acroding to the provided mock-data No5 student's balance is only 300 but with your sql its agregated with other student's balances at the result HTML no5 students balance looks like 800

Comment: @Santa'shelper yes, you are right. I messed up will data on last update. Thanks for pointing this

Comment: @RandomSeed done only first this that you pointed. Second its more up to OP to customize I guess. Thank for your contribution.

Comment: @Семенихин Максим after executing your code i'm getting   Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetchAll() in C:\xampp\htdocs\admission\test.php on line 152 (line num 152 is the 1st line of your code), as you instructed i skipped  db connect class  because i'm connecting to the database using mysqli code $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");

Comment: @Sha in my example I use PDO so you need use PDO(maybe my class) or replace PDO usage with mysqli functions

Comment: @ Семенихин Максим I'm not familiar with PDO can you please help me with mysqli procedural syntax

Comment: @ Семенихин Максим I'm awarding 50+ bounty to your answer please help me with mysqli procedural syntax instead PDO

Comment: @Sha ok then, create a chat

Comment: @Max i have created chat

Comment: @sha give me a link

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/117672/sha-and-max?tab=general

Comment: @Max Can you help me with mysqli procedural syntax instead of PDO

Comment: @sha yes, go to chat to toy  created and I will help you

Comment: @Max i have created room please follow the url http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/117672/sha-and-max?tab=general

Comment: @Max how to post there i don't know how to use chat

Comment: @ just go to link you provided,and it open up. if not pres `join room`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117885/discussion-between-sha-and--).